# Php check similarity of multiple strings

Tags: php, database, email, similarity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithms for string similarities (better than Levenshtein, and similar_text)? Php, Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351659/algorithms-for-string-similarities-better-than-levenshtein-and-similar-text)

I have a website that allow users to create accounts to refer others friend. And save these accounts into Database Table. But I have a problem is there's some people who create multiple account with email like nike@gmail.com, nike1@gmail.com, nike2@gmail.com and so on.

Is there a way to check that in the database is these email have more that three block all these email?

I am using Php for this application.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea. For each one of these you block, there may be a legitimate use such as foo.bar@msn.com and foobar@msn.com.

Comment: Yes there's a way but you will end up with lots of false positives.  How will you know that `nike@...` is not someone different from `nike1@...`?

Comment: hmmm, oh I didn't think about that one.. good one, Dam.

Comment: Because I dont want some spammers, who craete lot of emails like 1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on.

Comment: what you can try is register they ip on database and compare later.

Comment: oh something like that $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?

Comment: It's a really good idea Xd, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it isn't seems to be problem actually.
Because,
There can be different users with slight difference in their email id.

How can you tell that user with email ids : nike1@gmail.com and nike2@gmail.com are the same that of nike@gmail.com ?

but how ever if you want to check so :

1) You can remove the last numbers by using the regx or something similar
2) Then can check the original email id if it exists in your database.

Comment: Thanks, yea maybe your guys are right.