# Is the PHP levenshtein() function buggy?

Tags: php

On this page [levenshtein()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php), I am using the example #1 with following variables:

```
// input misspelled word
$input = 'htc corporation';

// array of words to check against
$words = array('htc', 'Sprint Nextel', 'Sprint', 'banana', 'orange',
        'radish', 'carrot', 'pea', 'bean');
```

Could someone please tell me why the expected result is **carrot** rather than **htc**? Thanks

Comment: I figure because your array already contains the exact word `htc`, that it is looking for something similar to your input string, so it's skipping `htc` because it didn't find anything else close to it, therefore `corporation` is closer to `carrot`. Least, that's my take on it and I never had to deal with this, yet alone knowing about the function until today.

Comment: This is why you can't use Levenshtein as such to implement a fuzzy search.

Comment: @Fred The algorithm doesn't "skip" anything. The distance is just greater with "htc" than with "carrot".

Comment: Have you had a look at [soundex()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) , [metaphone()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5430851/2493918? Also have a look at [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#PHP)

Comment: @Juhana Thanks for the clarification. Have a look at my edited comment, it will explain everything about "my take on it", cheers :)

Comment: You could make the result be `htc` by making insertions/deletions cheaper than replacements: `levenshtein('htc corporation', 'carrot', 1, 2, 1); // 13` If you are searching for a substring you may even want to make deletions free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance is a string metric for measuring the difference between two sequences. Informally, the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (insertion, deletion, substitution) required to change one word into the other.

here is a simple analysis

```
$input = 'htc corporation';

// array of words to check against
$words = array(
    'htc',
    'Sprint Nextel',
    'Sprint',
    'banana',
    'orange',
    'radish',
    'carrot',
    'pea',
    'bean' 
);

foreach ( $words as $word ) {

    // Check for Intercept
    $ic = array_intersect(str_split($input), str_split($word));

    printf("%s \t l= %s , s = %s , c = %d \n",$word ,  
    levenshtein($input, $word), 
    similar_text($input, $word), 
    count($ic));
}
```

Output

```
htc      l= 12 , s = 3 , c = 5 
Sprint Nextel    l= 14 , s = 3 , c = 8 
Sprint   l= 12 , s = 1 , c = 7 
banana   l= 14 , s = 2 , c = 2 
orange   l= 12 , s = 4 , c = 7 
radish   l= 12 , s = 3 , c = 5 
carrot   l= 11 , s = 1 , c = 10  
pea      l= 13 , s = 2 , c = 2 
bean     l= 13 , s = 2 , c = 2
```

It clear htc has a distance of `12` while carrot has `11` if you want htc then `Levenshtein` alone is not enough  .. you need to compare exact word then set priorities

Answer (score 4):

Because the levenshtein distance from `htc corporation` is 12 whereas the distance to carrot is only 11.

The levenshtein function calculates how many characters it has to add or replace to get to a certain word, and because `htc corporation` has 12 extra characters than `htc` it has to remove 12 to get to just `htc`. To get to the word `carrot` from `htc corporation` it takes 11 changes.

Comment: I got 11 too, but there could be a better way.

Comment: corporation has 11 letters, plus a space = 12

Comment: @Novocaine88 We're talking about the distance between "carrot" and "htc corporation". Remove 9 characters to get "corpot" and change 2 characters to get to "carrot"

Comment: ah ok, I wasn't sure about the calc to get to carrot.

Comment: I removed `9` characters to get `c crot` and then replaced the space and `c` to get `carrot` :)

Comment: It's definitely not 6 though, as just to get the strings to be the same length you need at least `9` operations.

Answer (score 3):

"htc corporation" to "htc" has a distance of 12 (remove " corporation" = 12 characters). "htc corporation" to "carrot" has a distance of no more than 11.

"htc corporation" => "corporation": 4
"corporation" => "corporat": 3
"corporat" => "corrat": 2
"corrat" => "carrat": 1
"carrat" => "carrot": 1

4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 11

It looks like what you might be looking for isn't straight-up levenshtein distance, but a "closest substring" match. There's an example implementation of such a thing using a modified Levenshtein algorithm [here](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/12/01/fuzzy-substring-matching-with-levenshtein-distance-in-python/). Using this algorithm gives scores of:

htc: 0
Sprint Nextel: 11
Sprint: 4
banana: 5
orange: 3
radish: 3
carrot: 3
pea: 2
bean: 3

which recognizes "htc" as an exact substring match and gives it a score of zero. The runner-up, "pea", has a score of two, because you could align it with the "p", the "e", or the "a" in corporation, and then replace the other two characters, etc. When working with this algorithm you should be aware that the score will never be higher than the length of the "needle" string, so shorter strings will generally get lower scores (they're "easier to match").